# React pushing array to state

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to push array of markers after clicking on map. I've tried this (under "this doesn't work") but it raise an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWO5N.png).

PS: how can I get location of my cursor to create new marker depending on cursor position?

I'm really stuck. Thanks for any advice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    markers: [
      {position: {lat:49.79, lng: 18}, key:1},
      {position: {lat:49.69, lng: 18}, key:2},
      //{position: {lat:49.59, lng: 18}, key:3}
    ]
  };

//this doesn't work

  handleMapClick() {

    this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, {position: {lat:49.59, 
    lng: 18}, key:3}]})
  }



   render() {
       const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
       <GoogleMap
          defaultCenter = { { lat: 49.82, lng: 18.16 } }
          defaultZoom = { 10 } 
          onClick = {this.handleMapClick}
       >

          {this.state.markers.map(marker => <Marker position= 
          {marker.position} key={marker.key} />)}
       </GoogleMap>
   ));
   return(
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
        containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `600px`, width: 
        '800px',display: "inline-block" }} /> }
        mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }



       />
       </div>
       );}};

 export default Map;
```

Comment: You likely did not preserve the `this` context in your callback (so it doesn't refer to your component instance). `console.log(this)` to verify this. You should `.bind(this)` where you pass the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Bind you your callback function or use arrow function

**binding**

```
onClick = {this.handleMapClick.bind(this)}
```

**arrow function**

```
onClick = {(arg) => this.handleMapClick(arg) }
```

From the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that
>   method.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your handleMapClick into an arrow function or bind it in constructor (these are equivalent solutions)

```
handleMapClick = () => {

    this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, {position: {lat:49.59, 
    lng: 18}, key:3}]})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create constructor to bind `this` to functions.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this)
}
```